# How to interrupt the window closing mechanism in scala swing

Tags: swing, scala, window, savefiledialog

I'm building a GUI with the `SimpleSwingApplication` trait in scala swing.
What I want to do is to provide a mechanism on close, that asks the user (Yes,No,Cancel) if he didn't save the document yet. If the user hits Cancel the `Application` shouldn't close. But everything I tried so far with `MainFrame.close` and `closeOperation` didn't work.

So how is this done in Scala Swing?

I'm on Scala 2.9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly different variation from what Howard suggested

```
import scala.swing._

object GUI extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new Frame {
    title="Test"

    import javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE
    peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)

    override def closeOperation() { showCloseDialog() }

    private def showCloseDialog() {
      Dialog.showConfirmation(parent = null,
        title = "Exit",
        message = "Are you sure you want to quit?"
      ) match {
        case Dialog.Result.Ok => exit(0)
        case _ => ()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By using `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` you are given a chance to define what should be done when a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING` event is received by the scala frame. When a scala frame receives a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event it reacts by calling `closeOperation`. Hence, to display a dialog when the user attempts to close the frame it is enough to override `closeOperation` and implement the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you. After removing the deprecations, this did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
import swing._
import Dialog._

object Test extends SimpleSwingApplication { 
  def top = new MainFrame { 
    contents = new Button("Hi")

    override def closeOperation { 
      visible = true
      if(showConfirmation(message = "exit?") == Result.Ok) super.closeOperation  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (at least not when it is a MainFrame), because the confirmation dialog only appears after the main window has already disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really familiar with scala swing but I found this code in some of my old test programs:

```
object GUI extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new Frame {
    title="Test"
    peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(0)

    reactions += {
      case WindowClosing(_) => {
        println("Closing it?")
        val r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit?")
        if (r == 0) sys.exit(0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure: is `sys.exit(0)` normal for this purpose? At first sight it seems too heavy, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I wanted to do; calling super.closeOperation didn't close the frame.  I would have just said that in a comment, but I am not yet allowed.

```
object FrameCloseStarter extends App {
  val mainWindow = new MainWindow()
  mainWindow.main(args)
}

class MainWindow extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "MainFrame"
    preferredSize = new Dimension(500, 500)
    pack()
    open()

    def frame = new Frame {
      title = "Frame"
      preferredSize = new Dimension(500, 500)
      location = new Point(500,500)
      pack()

      peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)

      override def closeOperation() = {
        println("Closing")
        if (Dialog.showConfirmation(message = "exit?") == Result.Ok) {
          peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
          close()
        }
      }
    }
    frame.open()
  }
}
```